# IIS Rewrite rule to Block any URL request with and Ampersand

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I keep getting requests with an ampersand in the address and it errors.  I'm trying to write a URL rule that if the requested URL contains an ampersand, abort the quest.  I made a start but it is erroring.

```
<rule name="Block Amps" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*&amp;*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
 </rule>
```

I tried with both & and & neither seemed to work.

Therefore if the following addresses are requested, they are aborted.

http://www.example/page1&

http://example.com/page1&page2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rule name="Block Amps" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*[&].*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks Dawid, I did have to change the url to ".*[&amp;]." tho.

Comment: Glad I could help:)